# How to make sessions persistent in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am able to create session temporarily but when navigating to any other page, the session goes away.

this is how I am assigning the session

```
session(['key' => $value ]);
session()->save();
```

The session sticks on the page load, but like i said, if i got to another page, the session does not stay persistent. Is there something I need to do to flag it to be persistent, or something with the config?

Comment: You'll want to investigate whether the various session middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` are enabled for your route. By default, they're only turned on in the `web` routes.

Comment: @ceejayoz so, would i want to assign all my routes to a group with that middleware? or make it so anything has it?

Comment: Depends on your use case. You can move all the `web` middleware into the always-on `$middleware` array if you like, if you're not using the API side of things.

Comment: @ceejayoz Just tried that and its still not persisting, Im wanting the  \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class , correct? ( I also tried putting all my routes into a Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {...}  )

Comment: I also noticed that the session storage is getting a new request when ever i refresh the home page...

Comment: You'll probably need the `AddQueuedCookiesToResponse` middleware, as a session relies on a session ID in a cookie.